# How to set path for MinTTY under windows/cygwin correctly?

Tags: windows, cygwin, path, environment-variables, mintty

I made windows shortcut with the following target:

```
D:\APPS\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/env PATH=/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH /bin/bash --login -i
```

I was expecting it prepend path with my given values, but it doesn't:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/usr/lib/lapack
```

i.e. `$PATH` text went into content without expansion.

How to overcome?

Comment: Most likely, your bash login shell does a hard reset of the PATH. Have a look at the initialization files run by an interactive login bash, or run it as `bash -x --login` and study the output. BTW, I run my _mintty_ simply with `C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -s 101,26 -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico  -o ThemeFile=Default1 -e /usr/bin/zsh -l -i` (I use zsh instead of bash, but you can do the same approach for bash), and do all setup which I need (`PATH` and so on) in my own startup files.

Comment: Note also that in the way you start it, `$PATH` won't be expanded. Which shell should do this? You are running this command obviously from within either PowerShell or Windows CMD shell, and both don't know `$PATH`.

Comment: See related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475618/where-is-cygwin-set-its-path-variable

Comment: Shouldn't **this** PATH setting go into /etc/profile ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I see this is coming a bit late, but hopefully it can help you or someone else having a similar problem.

Since you are running a Windows shortcut, instead of using the syntax for cygwin/*nix environment variable expansion (`$VAR_NAME`) you probably just need to use the syntax for Windows/CMD.exe expansion (`%VAR_NAME%`). Also, I am linking two Wikibooks below that should cover pretty much anything you ever need to do with batch files for future reference.

That said, I would have expected your syntax also to work, and I do imagine there is *some* way to have expansions happen on the "other side", so-to-speak. If I can find a way as I work on my terminal launch script I will update this answer.

*References:*

1. [Programming CMD](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Programming_CMD) *has most of the basic syntax and essential commands*
2. [Windows Batch Scripting](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting) *a fairly comprehensive reference for everything*

<sub>****Notes/Caveat Emptor****</sub>

<sub>*`cmd` shell scripting leaves a lot to be desired, and I think you can easily google for something that gives you a run down on all the details. I just wanted to mention it, and mention that there is nothing stopping you from using something like 'MinGW-x64' (I recommend researching the difference between 'MinGW-x64' and the original if you are in doubt; they are maintained by separate entities), or something like Cygwin, which you clearly already have some experience with, either of which will allow you to do `sh`/`bash` scripting.*</sub>

<sub>*MinGW-x64 is simplified and has an incomplete POSIX implementation due to some concepts that are incompatible with the Windows Subsystem without some additional support (well, the Microsoft VC runtime, I guess; and I think there are circumstances where you need to at least with MinGW [if not MinGW-x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614221/building-programs-which-run-without-extra-dlls-of-mingw-and-msys)) but I mention it first, since it is a 'native' (i.e. 'fast') solution.*</sub>

<sub>*Cygwin provides its 'compatibility layer' `.dll` that provides a fairly complete POSIX environment, at the cost of (a) some fairly siginificant overhead (at least in some cases) and (b) having a fairly complex extra `.dll` that has to be provided with any software you make with it, and at the cost/benefit (depending on your perspective) of being fairly well locked into the GPL if you use it for your project and link to the compatibility layer.*</sub>

<sub>*However, [as an alternative, this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11292801/832859) mentions Red Hat's Cygwin license offer for non-GPL license terms on Cygwin, if you so desire. (And, of course assuming that it's cost-effective for you and your project.) However, for personal or in-house shell scripting (i.e., not 'distributed', an, so, not covered by the GPL) it might very well be a good choice, and would almost certainly be better than futzing around with the idiosyncrasies of a DOS-era product still stuck supporting poor decisions made well over 30 years ago.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

By default, /etc/profile adds the Windows PATH to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`.

You want to have **in addition** the pathes `/local/bin:/usr/local/bin`. This is strange: The directory `/local` does not exist, and `/usr/local/bin` is in the path anyway.

However if you still want this kind of path extension to happen, I suggest that you do this addition inside your `~/.profile`, and not in the shortcut.